# connection time out error for tftp-server connection

Tags: tftp, juniper, gns3

When I try to establish a connection between the juniper router in gns3 and the tftp server, I get a connection delay.

I've tried starting junos from the juniper router's tftp server in gns3.
but I still get a connection time out, even though I've added firewall rules to accept the connection, and if I've stopped the firewall, I get the same result.